# Azure Web Jobs Pipeline [inject before a function instance is created]

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

Problem:

I have a Web Job that logs to ApplicationInsights. I have a custom TelemetryInitializer (that is registered as a singleton (with no options)) that add some contextual information to the request (representing a function invocation). The issue is, that Azure Web Jobs (from what I know) doesn't provide a statically available execution context (similar to HttpContext from asp.net). I tried to build my own (based on AsyncLocal) (initializing it via a FunctionInvocationFilter), but the context is not available from TelemetryInitializers, since they are being invoked from the thread created before, with different execution context. In order this to work - I need to initialize my context earlier, before the function instance (together with AppInsights stuff) is created.

I tried to search in the Web Jobs SDK sources, but couldn't find any place where I can inject my context initialization logic.

Question:

Does anybody know how to do that? Or maybe I can achieve the same differently?

Comment: Was able to implement the desired functionality with System.Diagnostics.Activity

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with System.Diagnostics.Activity, it can act as a context for logical operation. It is created very deep in WebJobs pipeline and AppInsights initializers share the operation context